# Register and execute a JavaScript function in a ASP.NET Page_Load event

Tags: javascript, asp.net, function

How can I register AND execute that JavaScript function in ASP.NET on a Page_Load event so my textbox content gets validated and if nothing is in there I can disable a save button?

```
function Validate(source, arguments)
{
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't a required field validator do this for you?  Why use 'raw' javascript?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to execute a javascript, get a result and according it disable button and do all that on a Page_Load?

Comment: Why are you trying to do it with JavaScript? You're saying you want to perform this check in the `Page_Load` and disable the submit button, so the value of the `TextBox` is set by the code behind and not the user (otherwise you would check it with a `RequiredFieldValidator` or a `CustomValidator`), so why don't you perform the check directly in the code behind?

Comment: @Five The RequiredFieldValidator does only validate when something is entered and removed again. It should trigger on the page_load event!

Comment: If so - you can reference both your text box and save button in the page load event.  If the text box text = string.empty disable your button. You could use the registerstartupscript below - but you're making extra work IMO.

Comment: Just to make sure - do you mean a SERVER SIDE Page_Load method or a client side pageLoad?

Comment: i thought a page is always run on the server and the client(browser) renders it into html...

Comment: @Five I could do that and disable the save button on page_Load but how do I trigger the Enable_Savebutton if the validatorcontrols do not have events I can subscribe on and check wether its still valid?

Comment: That's wrong. Server has render page and send html to client. And on a client all javascript are executed. So just add to the Page_Load following code: MyButton.Enabled = MyTextBox.Text.Length > 0;

Comment: @One thats ok for the startup but when the validation control is doing a validation I must catch that event (which is not subscribable) to enable my button...

Comment: Use a CustomValidator control.

Answer (score 1):

Use [ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx)

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx) for example

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">
  public void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    // Define the name and type of the client scripts on the page.
    String csname1 = "PopupScript";
    Type cstype = this.GetType();

    // Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
    ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

    // Check to see if the startup script is already registered.
    if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, csname1))
    {
        StringBuilder cstext1 = new StringBuilder();
        cstext1.Append("<script type=text/javascript> alert('Hello World!') </");
        cstext1.Append("script>");

        cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname1, cstext1.ToString());
    }
  }
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>RegisterStartupScript</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: How is it possible to debug the javascript if its build dynamically?

Comment: You can create not dynamically function, and call that function dynamically, it's just a sample @msfanboy

Comment: its not executed at the end of the page because the html control I search for is null.